# how to send data from server(API) to client?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm using MEAN Stack. I have API and made this url: `localhost:3001/api/profile/check` If I'm on this page, data is written on the page but now I want to send this data in client and when I'm on this page: `localhost:3000/profile`  must saw my info. how to make this with angular?

now I write my code what I have now.

profileController.js (client/angular):

```
angular.module('app').controller('profileController', ['$scope', '$cookies', '$location', 'profileService', function($scope, $cookies, $location, profileService) {
$scope.checkUser = function() {
    profileService.read().then(function(data) {
        $scope.userProfile = data;
    });
};
```

profileService.js (client/angular):

```
angular.module('app').factory('profileService', ['$http', '$q', 'appSettings', function($http, $q, appSettings) {
    return {
        read: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get(appSettings.apiServiceBaseUri + '/profile/check').success(function(data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function(data, status) {
                deferred.reject(data);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```

and this is profileController.js (server/node.js):

```
module.exports.check = function(req, res) {
    var user = req.cookies;

    User.UserModel.findById({ _id: user.user_id }, function(err, data) {
        res.send(data);
    });
};
```

Comment: Simply call `$scope.checkUser()` just after its definition

Comment: I tried this: console.log($scope.checkUser());  but result is: undefined

Comment: Place `console.log(data);` above `$scope.userProfile = data;`  and call `$scope.checkUser()` to see what data comes from server. The `checkUser()` function doesn't return any data so this `console.log($scope.checkUser());` is non-sense.

Comment: have you put console.log(data) be for the line deferred.resolve(data) ?

Comment: I tried that everywhere :/